# Javascript form only seems to submit properly to new tab, not same tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I know the title is weird, but I can't think of a succinct way of saying this:

This code creates a form and submits to a URL:

```
function post_to_url( path, params, method ) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    //form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    for ( var key in params ) {
        if ( params.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

As you can see, I've commented out the `target` attribute.

I have the following code that calls the function:

```
    var params = new Array();
    params["param1"] = param1;
    params["param2"] = param2;
    post_to_url('newTask.php', params, "get");
```

If I have the target attribute set to `_blank` so it opens a new tab, the function works just fine and I can see my params right there in the url bar.
But if I remove the `target` attribute (which I would prefer), it seems as if the page just refreshes. No params in the URL, and the page doesn't act as if it has received data.

Can someone help me track this down please?

Comment: how about `target="_self"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
form.setAttribute("target", "_self");
```